# C# display waveform

Tags: c#, waveform

Using this:

```
 public static void DrawNormalizedAudio(ref float[] data, PictureBox pb,
    Color color)
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    if (pb.Image == null)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        bmp = (Bitmap)pb.Image;
    }

    int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
    int width = bmp.Width - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);
    int height = bmp.Height - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        Pen pen = new Pen(color);
        int size = data.Length;
        for (int iPixel = 0; iPixel < width; iPixel++)
        {
            // determine start and end points within WAV
            int start = (int)((float)iPixel * ((float)size / (float)width));
            int end = (int)((float)(iPixel + 1) * ((float)size / (float)width));
            float min = float.MaxValue;
            float max = float.MinValue;
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                float val = data[i];
                min = val < min ? val : min;
                max = val > max ? val : max;
            }
            int yMax = BORDER_WIDTH + height - (int)((max + 1) * .5 * height);
            int yMin = BORDER_WIDTH + height - (int)((min + 1) * .5 * height);
            g.DrawLine(pen, iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMax, 
                iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMin);
        }
    }
    pb.Image = bmp;
}
```

I got an error at this line:

```
g.DrawLine(pen, iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMax, 
            iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMin);
```

It says operation overflow(cannot divide by zero) or something like that. Any clue on the problem? Thanks.

UPDATE:
The codes i use to call the function is:

```
fileName = "c:\\sound\\happy_birthday.wav";

        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        float[] getval = FloatArrayFromByteArray(bytes);
        DrawNormalizedAudio(ref getval, pictureBox1, Color.White);
```

Comment: Something like that or is it divide by zero?

Comment: What are yMax and yMin at that point?

Comment: @Bobby Alexander - It just says Additional information: Overflow error.

Comment: @jonsca - ymax is 41, ymin is -2147483572.

Comment: Is it possible that DrawLine is computing the slope of the line for some reason, since your x values are the same, that may be what's causing the problem, but I don't know that for sure.  Try making the second x value `iPixel+BORDER_WIDTH+5` or something.

Comment: You mean int yMin = BORDER_WIDTH + 5 - (int)((min + 1) * .5 * height);?

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing by zero. Don't do it, as this operation is invalid. Check the values you pass to `DrawLine` are not 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int yMin = BORDER_WIDTH + height - (int)((min + 1) * .5 * height);
```

You are using the signed int data type - what happens is that this calculation overflows and results in a negative value, you get `-2147483572` which is `int.MaxValue+75` (overflow), could it be that `min` is a large negative value that causes the result to be 75 larger than `int.MaxValue` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how I got the values flipped. However, if the value for ymin is 75, it don't look logical considering the ymax value is 41?

Comment: @cnewbie: was in progress of editing my answer - what is the value of `min` ?

Comment: oh I see. sorry. the value for min is -3.296672E+38. seems the problem is with the min value right? however, looking from the code it seems like its taken and processed from the byte array.

Comment: @cnewbie: there you have your problem

Comment: @cnewbie: this is the equivalent of `Math.Min(val, min)`

Answer (score 0):

The `min` and `max` were wrong, should be

```
float min = float.MinValue;
float max = float.MaxValue;
```

Comment: No, they are set correctly - before searching for maximum and minimum value in a set, initial value of max should be set to min and initial value of min should be set to max. Otherwise algorithm won't work.